# Incrementing Variables in Yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to increment a variable value by 1. Below is my code

```
 variables:
     a: 0

   steps:
     script: |
       if [ $a == 0 ]; then
           echo $a
           $a=$a+1
       fi
       echo $a
```

but its not incrementing

I tried many types of incrementing formats, below are the list i tried,

```
((a+1))
   a=$((a+=1))
  let "a=a+1"
  a=$((a + 1))
  $[counter('$(a),1)]
  a: $[counter(1)]
```

none of the above format is incrementing my variable.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation: [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)

In this case, your yaml may look like this:

```
variables:
  a: 0

steps:
  script: |
    a = $(a)
    if [ $a == 0 ]; then
        echo $a
        $a=$a+1
    fi
    echo $a
```

If you want to use an updated value in the next script task, you have to add

`echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=a;]"$a`

Check [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash)